# javascript executor set attribute values is not working properly

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In selenium web driver, i want to set the position of a container and i used the following code:

```
jse.executeScript("$('#library-inspector-header').click();", "");
```

this is used to click on header of container.Than to set its position i used this :

```
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#library-inspector-container').style.height = 300+'px'");
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#library-inspector-container').style.width = 300+'px'");
makeWait(2);

jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#library-inspector').style.top = 71+'px'");
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#library-inspector').style.right = 0+'px'");
```

I used this code in a function name

```
setPostion()
```

i use this function three times in my code.
But the problem is first time it set position properly.

But the second time it makes my height

```
300+300=600
```

and also to other attributes.

i Want to resolve this that means each time i want height as

```
300
```

Please give any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
300+'px'
```

use

```
'300px'
```

e.g.

```
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector(...).style.height = '300px'");
```

If you aren't trying to use a variable height, there's not much point in adding a number to `'px'`.